# clientX/Y affected by Margins - skews jQuery/CSS cursor effect

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, blogger, mousemove

**Original Title**: jQuery trailing .Cursor (mouse) effect not working as expected on Blogger (**Edited**)

​

Been racking my brain with this trailing cursor effect.

For whatever reason it shows up **marginally off** in my **Blogger/BS4** website (stripped Blogger template with BS 4 added), yet **displays just fine** in a **Codepen**.

​

The trailing circles **coordinates are off** by about **-15px** (left) / **- 30px** (top) in my Blogger/BS4 implementation. Now I could simply incorporate these offsets to my **clientX** / **ClientY** coordinates to get the right result e.g.

```
var x = e.clientX + $(window).scrollLeft() -15;
var y = e.clientY + $(window).scrollTop() -30;
```

However, **without understanding what's causing the offset** the worry is that it will display differently for other users/devices/screens or even different pages.

In fact I did try this on a more complex Blogger implementation and the clientY coordinates on the other site where off by another 50px or so. Manually hacking this template wide may not be such a good idea as it could be fine on the landing page and totally off on another page!

​

**NB** I enabled the pointer for this demo, but the way it's supposed to work is with `cursor: none;` so that the two circling points become the cursor!

​

Any **pointers** would be appreciated ;)

​

---

​
**UPDATED :**

After the initial response it appears that **client**X/Y (also tried pageX/Y, screenX/Y etc) are **affected by margins** set on elements within my document.

In my particular reduced test case it's the .widget and .section margins applied by Blogger, but on other pages there will undoubtedly be other element margins present e.g. another blogger page I have it's more like -15px (left) / - **85px** (top). Tweaking any set page/element margins is out of the question, so the bigger question really is:

**why are margins interfering with clientX/Y usage** in the first place.

My understanding is that clientX/Y measures coordinates from the viewpoint and I just can't understand why margins would have such an impact.

---

​

Problematic Blogger demo: https://magicmbblog.blogspot.com/p/custom-circle-cursor.html (now **working** with `<nav>` **fix applied** to it!)

Working CodePen: https://codepen.io/magicmb/pen/MMoabE

​

CODE:

```
<div class="cursor"></div>
<div class="cursor"></div>

<div class="blank"></div>


<style >
html,*{ margin:0; padding:0;}
*{
    /*cursor: none;*/
}

.blank {
  height: 200vh;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(https://picsum.photos/2200/1900/?random) center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  /*display: flex;*/
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.cursor:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #D26;
  z-index: 1;
}
.cursor:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document)
  .mousemove(function(e) {

    $('.cursor')
      .eq(0)
      .css({
        left: e.clientX + $(window).scrollLeft(),
        top: e.clientY + $(window).scrollTop()
      });
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.cursor')
        .eq(1)
        .css({
          left: e.clientX + $(window).scrollLeft(),
          top: e.clientY + $(window).scrollTop()
        });
    }, 100);
  })
</script>
```

Comment: This is because the mouse element is inside your #main element which has a margin of 0 15px; either remove the margin or bring the mouse element outside of it.

Comment: Hi Waldir. I don't believe this is the case. I previously moved the cursor element from the website page into the blogger template and placed it just below <body> as part of Rory's suggestions and this didn't work. I moved it back there just now, but this hasn't fixed it.

Comment: I want to get away from overriding any of the template margins etc  as suggested by Rory and I initially just subtracted the -15px (left) / - 30px (top) to get it to how I like it to be, but as it turns out zooming in and out can skews the position slightly again (as I found out on another Dev page), so I also want to get away from having to hardcoding the offset difference as it can potentially change.

Comment: Moving the cursor element first time around to just below <body> didn't work, but bizarrely moving it inside an empty <nav> did the trick. I've updated the demo to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The problems in the working example are caused by the `margin` on parent elements. Specifically the left value on `.section { margin: 0 15px; }` and the top value on `.widget { margin: 30px 0; }`.

There's two fixes for this. Firstly, you could set negative margin on the `.cursor` elements itself to offset whatever's been set on the parents.

Secondly you could move the `.cursor` elements to sit in the root of the `body` so that no parent styling affects them in any way.

I'd suggest using the latter.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the super speedy response Rory )

I tried to follow your second suggestion and moved the `.cursor` elements into the Blogger template itself and placed them right under the <body> tag, but this didn't have the required effect.

Not sure if this is what you meant by "sit in the root of the body". If not please re-phrase )

In any case I added the following override CSS:

`.section{ margin: 0 !important; }
.widget{margin: 0 !important;}`

Hopefully this won't have any adverse effects.

Oddly enough the pointer is still marginally off by a few px! Any idea why?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant by root of the body. If it's still out by some px then there will be other margins added somewhere.

Comment: I just realised this is a test site and I wouldn't be able to mess with some of the margins without adversely affecting the layout of pages (

Ach! Unfortunately this is not the quick fix I was hoping for!

To tell you the truth I still can't wrap my head around how the Margings affect the implementation of the cursor. Aren't clientX and clientY supposed to measure coordinates from the Screen Viewpoint and if so, why do these margins come into it at all?

Answer (score 0):

I am still not entirely sure what the issue was with the margins throwing things off, but as it turns out when I moved the `<div class="cursor"></div>` on one of my other development blogs inside the `<nav class="navbar2">` Bootstrap navbar element, it resolved the problem for me entirely.

Even though I haven't got a navbar in my reduced test case demo, I simply created an empty one and placed the cursor element inside this

```
<nav class="navbar2">
  <div class="cursor"></div>
  <div class="cursor"></div>
</nav>
```

This resolved the issue here as well.

So whether this is Bootstrap4 related or Blogger related I don't know, but this did the trick for me. I will add a Bootstrap4 tag to this StackOverflow question just in case someone else is having similar issues.